# Assigning a value which comes from a loop to an array

Tags: c

I have a program. Firstly, it founds prime numbers in a range entered by user. Then it checks the primeness of 2times these prime numbers +1(finds germain primes basically). When i want to print out germain primes directly, it works. But when I try to assign these values into a array and print them, just the first value is printed. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100
    
int main(){
    int x, y, i, ii, j, k, m, storage[MAX], counter=0, counter2=0;
    
    printf("Please enter the X and Y values:\a\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
       
    for(i=x;i<=y;i++)
    {
        for(j=2;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if (counter==0){
            //printf("%d is a prime number\n",i);
            for(k=2;k<(2*i+1);k++)
            {
                if((2*i+1)%k==0){
                    counter2++;
                }
            }
        }
                    
        if (counter2==0){
            printf("%d is a germain prime\n",i);
        }
                        
                        
        for(ii=0; ii<=i; ii++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&storage[ii]);
            //printf("%d", storage[ii]);
        }       
    }
    
    counter2=0;
    counter=0;
    
    return 0;
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Where do you assign the germain prime to the array?

Comment: The only code that uses the array is `scanf("%d",&storage[ii]);` which asks the user to enter the numbers.

Comment: Also, use proper variables names instead of i,ii, etc.  Very hard to read.

Comment: You need to set `counter = 0;` at the beginning of the outer loop.

Comment: i wrote the last loop for taking these i values and assigning to an array

Comment: If you want to save the value in the array you should do `storage[ii] = i` , with the scanf you're asking the user to give you an input.

Comment: yeah i haven't realized that i used scanf. I changed it but now i have interesting values. I will add a screenshot of output. can you check it?

Comment: Be sure to reset `counter`  to 0 at the start of your first `for`  loop, otherwise you'll be using the value from previous loops.

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding:  (the compiler does not care)  regarding: `int x, y, i, ii, j, k, m, storage[MAX], counter=0, counter2=0;`  1) Please use meaningful variable names.  Names like: `x` `y` `i` `ii` `j` `k` `m` are meaningless, even in the current context. 2) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize `counter` and `counter2` to `0` each time through the main loop.

You need another variable to hold the index into the `storage` array for the next germain number. Then when you find a germain number, assign it to the array element and increment this variable.

The test for whether a number is a germain prime should be inside the conditional that it's a prime.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100
    
int main(){
    int x, y, i, ii, j, k, m, storage[MAX], s_index = 0;
    
    printf("Please enter the X and Y values:\a\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
       
    for(i=x;i<=y;i++)
    {
        int counter = 0, counter2 = 0;
        for(j=2;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if (s_index < MAX && counter==0){
            //printf("%d is a prime number\n",i);
            for(k=2;k<(2*i+1);k++)
            {
                if((2*i+1)%k==0){
                    counter2++;
                }
            }
            if (counter2==0){
                //printf("%d is a germain prime\n",i);
                storage[s_index++] = i;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(ii=0; ii<s_index; ii++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", storage[ii]);
    }       
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this prints all numbers in given interval. And i have a strange must that i can not use break or continue. But i'll try to logic

Comment: If you remove the various `break` it doesn't change much, by using it you're just exiting the loop faster without needing to check the `if` or `for` condition again. 
The one at `if (s_index>=MAX)` is important to avoid overflow in the buffer tho, in this case you should check this condition before accessing `storage`

Comment: Found the problem. The `counter2` test needs to be inside `if (counter == 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you want to find all the Germain primes in a given range and you are having issues with printing them. As Barmar has already pointed out the actual issue, here's a small word of advice:

The code would be a little easier to debug if you separated out the test for whether a number is prime or not into a separate function. Something like this may help:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int is_prime(int num){
    int prime = 0;

    int sqrt_num = ( (int) sqrt( (double) num) ) + 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= sqrt_num; i++){
        if( num % i == 0 ){
            return prime;
        }
    }
    // otherwise: is prime
    prime = 1;
    return prime;
}

int main(){
    const int MAX = 100;

    int primes[MAX];
    int range_min = 20;
    int range_max = range_min + MAX;

    // find germain primes
    int prime_count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        int prime_candidate = range_min + i;

        if( is_prime(prime_candidate) && is_prime(2*prime_candidate + 1) ){
            primes[prime_count] = prime_candidate;
            prime_count++;
        }
    }

    // print them
    for(int i = 0; i < prime_count; i++){
        printf("%d is a germain prime\n", primes[i] );
    }

}
```

Comment: using functions make the life easier and better, unfortunately i can't use them for now.